# How can i update one bound value when another value changes?

Tags: knockout-2.0

I have a smiple select control bound to model that contains 2  values: id -the value i want to bind to selected index, and cities= array i want ooptions populated from.
here is the JS:

```
    var VM=function ViewModel() {
      self=this;


        this.id = ko.observable(102);
        this.cities=ko.observableArray([]); 

        this.getCities=function(){ 
              self.cities( [{"Key":"-1","Value":"choose city"},{"Key":"100","Value":"leningrad"},   {"Key":"102","Value":"moscow"}]); 
        } ;
    }

    var vm=new VM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I want cities to be populted after user clicked button, but the selected city must stay Moscow (because initialy the "id" was 102)

here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <select data-bind="options:cities,optionsText:'Value',optionsValue:'Key',value:id"></select>

      <button data-bind="click:getCities">get cities</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My problem is that selected index got lost after cities is loaded
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where my problem is:
the 'value' binding is two directional, so when firstly bound to select without options -the 'id' became -1.
When i cahnged to :

```
  <select data-bind="options:cities,optionsText:'Value',optionsValue:'Key'"></select>
```

and added:

```
    this.getCities=function(){ 
          self.cities( [{"Key":"-1","Value":"choose city"},{"Key":"100","Value":"leningrad"},   {"Key":"102","Value":"moscow"}]
                     ); 


      $('select').val(self.id());
    } ;
```

The things started to work,
but problem now is how to collect value if user chooses some city after select populated:
my solution is to attach select change to unobtrusive jquery handler:

```
          var VM=function ViewModel() {
          self=this;


            this.id = ko.observable(102);
            this.cities=ko.observableArray([]); 

            this.getCities=function(){ 
                  self.cities( [{"Key":"-1","Value":"choose city"},{"Key":"100","Value":"leningrad"},   {"Key":"102","Value":"moscow"}]
                             ); 


              $('select').val(self.id());
            } ;



        };
    var f=function(){
      vm.id($('select').val())



    }
        var vm=new VM();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    $('select').change(f)
```

I hope it will help somebody who experienced my problem...